# Inconsistent result with Sqoop

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, hdfs, sqoop

Using Sqoop to get data from a MySQL database has inconsistent results whether it is run from the shell or from a python subprocess.  However, I don't have this issue doing the same thing when accessing an Oracle db, even from the same python session.

The following runs as expected from the shell:

```
export username="user1"

URI="jdbc:mysql://$host/dbname"
URI="${URI}?verifyServerCertificate=false"
URI="${URI}&useSSL=true"
URI="${URI}&requireSSL=false"

## List Tables
sqoop list-tables  \
    --connect ${URI} \
    --username ${username} \
    --password-file password.file
```

However the exact same thing does not run from a python subprocess:

```
import subprocess

## List Tables
subprocess.Popen(
    'sqoop list-tables --connect jdbc:mysql://$host/dbname?verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&requireSSL=false --username user1 --password-file password.file',
shell=True)
```

gives the following error:

```
ERROR [main] manager.CatalogQueryManager (LoggingUtils.java:logAll(43)) - Failed to list tables
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'100.100.100.100' (using password: NO)
```

Is there something else I have to do to connect to a MySQL database using Sqoop through a python subprocess?

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out immediately after posting.  Perhaps it can help someone else.

I needed to wrap the connection string in `""`.

The following is a neater python representation.

```
import subprocess

with open('lbaDevUsername.file', 'r') as f:
    username = f.read()

URI = "jdbc:mysql://$host/dbname"
URI = "{}?verifyServerCertificate=false".format(URI)
URI = "{}&useSSL=true".format(URI)
URI = "{}&requireSSL=false".format(URI)

## List Tables
subprocess.Popen("""
sqoop list-tables \
--connect "{}" \
--username {} \
--password-file password.file 
""".format(URI, username), shell=True)
```